# Multiplying Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How can I show that the product of two cdfs also have the properties of a cdf?

Comment: Hint: The product of two cdfs is indeed a cdf. However, the analogous statement for pdfs doesn't hold. Consider the pdf of $ Exp(1) $ and the pdf of $ U(0,1) $.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes. 
We want to show that $F(x)G(x)$ is continuous from the right, and non-decreasing, both of which can follow from the definitions and are easy to verify.

And good luck with the homework. Don't forget to print out a copy as well :)